# Can GSON deserialize in a case-insensitive way

Tags: java, json, gson

In prototyping communication between .NET desktop app and Java server, using REST with JSON posts, I am running into a case-sensitivity issue.  The .NET objects have there properties in Pascal Casing (which is conventional for .NET), e.g.:  `Symbol, EntryValue` (etc), while the Java representation of same object uses camel casing, e.g. `symbol, entryValue`.

The server receives json value as:

```
{"EntrySize":100,"Symbol":"AMZN"}
```

But Gson doesn't deserialize in case-insensitive manner.  Is there any way to get Gson to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`FieldNamingPolicy`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html) on a [`GsonBuilder`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html), to get your `Gson` object. Yours seems to match [`UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
        .create();
```

For any exceptions, annotate your class field with a [`@SerializedName`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

Comment: Awesome! This was easily fixed using the UPPER_CAMEL_CASE policy.  We did you find this in the docs?  In my rush to test this out, I wasn't able to fully read docs, and quick searches didn't point out the answer as clearly as you did. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam It's far down the page in the [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support). Make sure you poke around GsonBuilder to see all of the configurations Gson supports!

Comment: @Jeff Bowman This is actually not a valid solution, because it does NOT match case insensitive. It only matches either what is defined in SerializedName or if it starts with a big letter in camel case style. If there is a json which starts with a small letter (without a SerializedName annotation), it will not match.

Comment: @Bevor: I agree that this is not a general solution to all requests for case-insensitivity, which gets tricky anyway. _What if you have `entrysize`, `ENTRYSIZE`, and `EntrySize` in the same JSON object? Which wins?_
However, it _does_ allow the OP to do what they want to do, which is to get lower-camel naming on the server to work with upper-camel naming on the client, and it seems that even in that limited scope the community has found the answer useful.

Comment: See also this article : [Gson Builder — Basics & Naming Policies](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-builder-basics-naming-policies)