# Retrofit POJO is null but JSON is valid

Tags: android, json, pojo, retrofit

Have been scratching my head on this one. The JSON Response is a valid one:

```
{
    "MRData": {
        "xmlns": "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4",
        "series": "f1",
        "url": "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/2.json",
        "limit": "30",
        "offset": "0",
        "total": "1",
        "RaceTable": {
            "season": "2014",
            "round": "2",
            "Races": [
                {
                    "season": "2014",
                    "round": "2",
                    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Malaysian_Grand_Prix",
                    "raceName": "Malaysian Grand Prix",
                    "Circuit": {
                        "circuitId": "sepang",
                        "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepang_International_Circuit",
                        "circuitName": "Sepang International Circuit",
                        "Location": {
                            "lat": "2.76083",
                            "long": "101.738",
                            "locality": "Kuala Lumpur",
                            "country": "Malaysia"
                        }
                    },
                    "date": "2014-03-30",
                    "time": "08:00:00Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The POJO for the response:

```
public class ApiResponse {
    MRData mrdata;

    public class MRData {
        String xmlns;
        String series;
        String url;
        String limit;
        String offset;
        String total;
        RaceTable raceTable;
    }
}
```

The apiResponse object is always null. Anyone can point out what is wrong with the POJO object here?
Thanks.

Comment: We had an issue using `Gson` to deserialize JSON and found case sensitivity was the culprit  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171058/can-gson-deserialize-in-a-case-insensitive-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of potential issues here:

1. You are defining a class inside another class; I have never seen it done like this. You might want to separate in two different files.
2. Your variable names on your POJO should match the variable names on the JSON response exactly. For example:

`public class ApiResponse {MRData MRData;}`

If you want your POJO's variables to be different than what the JSON sends back, you should use `@SerlizedName`.

Comment: AFAIK we can have class inside another class, that also work.

Comment: @Emmanuel - The first point that you made is invalid. I have been using retrofit for quite some time and that pattern is really common. The casing was the issue for me.! Thanks

Comment: It was not so much making a point as a "maybe this is causing problems". I have never seen it done that way. Glad your problem was fixed.